# An interesting finding on twin primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, twin-primes

I was doing some research on prime gaps including twin primes and this led me to this finding, which is:

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi^2(n)}{n\pi_2(n)} = 0.7550363087870907 \cdots\cdots (1) $$

where the symbols have their usual meanings. Chart shown below.
[[image: <span class=]$\frac{\pi^2(n)}{n\pi_2(n)}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5VCc.png)

The number $0.755..$ did not make any sense to me until accidentally I inverted it in my Jupyter notebook which resulted in:

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{n\pi_2(n)}{\pi^2(n)} = 1.3203236316937392 \cdots\cdots (2) $$

Chart shown below.
[[image: <span class=]$\frac{n\pi_2(n)}{\pi^2(n)}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di3zj.png)

Now $1.32032... = 2C_2$ where $C_2$ is the twin prime constant.

**Question**: It appears the graphs are converging but that could be just an illusion. Is the second chart indeed converging to $2C_2$?

Philosophically it would make sense as it gives real meaning to the twin prime constant. This if true will obviously prove the twin prime conjecture. This result is a much stronger result than the Hardy-Littlewood twin prime conjecture. Of course, how I arrived at this is perhaps more interesting but that would take up too much space here.

Finally if we rewrite (2) as:
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{\pi_2(n)}{\pi(n)}}{\frac{\pi(n)}{n}} = 1.3203236316937392 \cdots\cdots (3) $$

which is saying the number of twin primes in primes is more than the number of primes in $n$.

Comment: Conjecturally, we do expect the graph to converge to $2 C_2$. You can see this by using the prime number theorem and the conjectured count of twin primes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the prime number theorem, we have that
$$ \pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log n}. $$
The first Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture implies that
$$ \pi_2(n) \sim 2 C_2 \frac{n}{\log^2(n)},$$
where
$$ C_2 = \prod_{p \geq 3} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{(p-1)^2} \right) \approx 0.6601\ldots$$
is the twin-prime constant. Thus we would expect
$$ \frac{\pi^2(n)}{n \pi_2(n)} = \pi^2(n) \frac{1}{n \pi_2(n)} \sim
\frac{n^2}{\log^2 n} \frac{1}{n \frac{2 C_2 n}{ \log^2 n}} = \frac{1}{2 C_2},$$
agreeing with your observation.

Comment: The interesting thing is that although the formulas used for both $\pi(n)$ and $\pi_2(n)$ are approximations, the errors in each of those formulas get offset when we take the ratio resulting in a constant, which is amazing!